# how to write hexadecimal values to a binary file

Tags: java

Im currently trying to build a save editor for a video game. Anyway the I figured out how to write to the binary file with output stream rather than writer I'm running into a problem. I'm trying to overwrite certain hexadecimal values but every time I try I end up replacing the whole file, theres probably an easy explanation for this but I also wanted advice on how to replace the hex values converting the hex values (ex. 5acd) from a string only gives me the byte data for the strings. Heres what I'm doing:

```
    String textToWrite = inputField.getText();
    byte[] charsToWrite = textToWrite.getBytes();

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(theFile);


    out.write(charsToWrite, 23, charsToWrite.length)
```

Comment: did you check this out?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289965/inserting-text-into-an-existing-file-via-java

Comment: yes, I did it was a little different than what I was asking but gave me a little more insight. Im interested in binary manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).  This has the methods that you are looking for.  `FileOutputStream` will only allow you to overwrite or append.  However, note as Murali VP eluded to, this will only allow you to perform direct replacements (byte-for-byte) - and not removal or insertion of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Converting from Hex String to Byte Array (which is essentially what you need) - see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/140861/739090) for what you need.

HTH