# Write a text in continue of a line in java

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

In Java I want to write a String to end of a specific line in file. The simple way:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));
bw.write(String);
```

does not work because it always writes at the end of file. Is there a simple way?

Comment: No, you will have to create a new file. Read all lines from the original file and copy them unaltered to the new file. When you reach the line that needs modification simply write that line + the new stuff to the file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting text into an existing file via Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289965/inserting-text-into-an-existing-file-via-java)

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the line number where you want to add the string.... Then iterate over the the file with [`readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()).

```
while (br.readLine() != null) {
   if (actualLine == yourLine) // write the String
   actualLine ++;
}
```