# How to insert a string into a specific position in a file using Java?

Tags: java

Lets say hello.txt contains the string `"Hello John"`. I have a string variable `str="dear"`. I need to insert it directly into the file after Hello i.e. after 5th position. After executing the function file must contain `"Hello dear John"`.

Is there a function for this in Java?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to load the entire file as a single String (using one of the methods describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-do-i-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file)), then create an instance of StringBuilder from that String and finally use [method `java.lang.StringBuilder.insert(int dstOffset, CharSequence s)`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/stringbuilder_insert_sequence.htm) to insert your text and then overwrite the original file with the contents of the builder:

```
String fileName = "file.txt";
String fileContents = loadFile(fileName);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(fileContents);
String str = "dear";

builder.insert(5, str);

saveFile(fileName, builder.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is 'saveFile' a user defined function? If not which package do I have to import? I'm sorry, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Yes, it's a user defined function.

Comment: Here are some ideas as to how to implement it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java

Answer (score 0):

You could make the hello.txt contain "Hello {TO_BE_REPLACED} John", read that line or the entire file content into a `String yourString` and then do

`yourString = yourString.replace("{TO_BE_REPLACED}", "Dear");`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But as I mentioned in the question, I need to insert string directly into my file. Is there any way of doing it without defining a string variable? Something like "insert(file, position, string)".

Comment: I think (but am not sure) you can use a [`FileChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) to do so... There is [a question at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289965/inserting-text-into-an-existing-file-via-java) with an answer about those.